# Reset password for phpmyadmin on raspberry pi

Tags: mysql, password, raspberrypi, phpmyadmin

I’ve got a raspberry pi with a phpmyadmin database. However I can not remember the password. I may not even have a password. I have tried various method of resetting the password but when I try

```
mysql -p -u root
```

I get an error no matter what I put in the password box. This is the error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can’t connect to local MySQL server through socket ‘/bar/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock’ (2)
```

Any ideas to fix?
Many thanks.

Comment: Is your `mysql` process running? Try `ps -ef|grep mysql` or `systemctl status mysql` if you're on a `systemd` version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @Jos I got ‘’’Unit mysqll.service could not be found’’’

Comment: Then you haven't installed `mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

Go go step 3 on this [page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04).  Do it.

It is the Digital Ocean solution.  I have tried all other solutions and this one works every time.

You need to allow password authentication and off you go.

Comment: This didn’t work. Exact same error

Comment: Sorry about that.  in the first command make sure you run sudo mysql and not sudo mysql -u. . . Don't specify a user.

Answer (score 0):

I realised I had to uninstall then reinstall phpmyadmin as I could not login and had no password. The problem is fixed now.